# could you see any implication in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> ....Whenever I hear a mother say," if so-and-so told you to jump off the Brooklyn Bridge, would you do it?" I think of her. On my order, she would have jumped.

(sources: [Anna Quindlen: Living Out Loud, p.250](https://books.google.de/books?id=qWqqyAlvUeIC&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=....Whenever+I+hear+a+mother+say,%22+if+so-and-so+told+you+to+jump+off+the+Brooklyn+Bridge,+would+you+do+it?%22+I+think+of+her.+On+my+order,+she+would+have+jumped.&source=bl&ots=FeDvCXp4HX&sig=m2JW5GW_O2WRbJzk-eOE_Yw_DPg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=C7MyVa2IMI3XauP_gLgB&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=....Whenever%20I%20hear%20a%20mother%20say%2C%22%20if%20so-and-so%20told%20you%20to%20jump%20off%20the%20Brooklyn%20Bridge%2C%20would%20you%20do%20it%3F%22%20I%20think%20of%20her.%20On%20my%20order%2C%20she%20would%20have%20jumped.&f=false) / [Anna Quindlen: Life In The 30's, NY Times 1986](http://www.nytimes.com/1986/07/16/garden/life-in-the-30-s.html))

Would you show me if there is any implication in the sentence?-as I cannot get what is the concept of the sentence- although I know what the sentence almost means.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it - what exactly is the qestion?

Comment: Is the whole first part "....Whenever I hear a mother say,'if so-and-so told you to jump off the Brooklyn Bridge, would you do it?' I think of her. On my order, she would have jumped" a quote and where from? For which of these sentences are you asking whether there's any implication in it?

Comment: Nima, please *always give the source of quotes*! According to your profile, you do have academic background, so you really should know better.

Comment: The essay is a remembrance about a close friend from high school.  The narrator is telling us that whenever she hears a mother scolding her child for following a friend's lead, unquestioning, she (the narrator) thinks of her old friend.  They got in lots of trouble, and most of the time, it was the narrator who was doing the planning, and telling her friend what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're to imagine a conversation like this:

> Mother: Why did you do that? 
>   Child: Jimmy told me to. 
>   Mother: If Jimmy told you to jump off the Brooklyn Bridge, would you do it?

(In other words, the mother is saying that "Jimmy told me to" is not a convincing reason for doing something.)

The narrator is saying that whenever she hears a conversation like this, she thinks of this friend, because this friend always did whatever the narrator wanted.

---

I have to say, though, that I've never heard of a conversation like the above. A much more common variant, in my experience, is:

> Mother: Everyone else is doing it! 
>   Mother: If everyone else jumped off a bridge, would you?

(Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1170/.)